# Google spreadsheet - how to determine timezone using function

Tags: timezone, google-sheets, utc, epoch

How to use a formula to determine the current timezone?
The formula I use gives an unexpected result.

My spreadsheet settings (File > Spreadsheet settings...):
Time zone: **(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam**

The formula I used:
**=TEXT(NOW(),"HH:mm z")**

This gives:
**12:47 GMT**

Local clock time is 12:47, I would expect the formula to show: "**12:47 GMT+1**".
I also tried Z instead of z, which gives "12:47 +0000", I would expect +1.

Any suggestions?

I need this so I can determine UTC time and convert to Epoch time ("UTC time" - DATE(1970,1,1)*24*60*60)

Comment: I've reproduced your results and wasn't able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using formulas w/o javascript checking your local timezone.
As per this form:

https://docs.google.com/a/codeproject.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqhqY231XZd3cFBiY2VqeWdmNWdaX25zN2lpekthQlE&hl=en_US#gid=4

timezone formatting stuff is not supported in `TEXT`. This spreadsheet was done by one of Stackoverflow contributors, it is not mine.

So... script?

Answer (score 0):

=TEXT( NOW()+x/24 , "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss" )

=TEXT( NOW()+8/24 , "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss" )

The (+x/24) after the NOW function will add x hours (in my case 8) to the standard time. NOW()+1 will give you the time tomorrow so working bakc or forward you can set the formula to give different time zones.

Hope this helps,

Robbie

Comment: The question is not: how to show it in a different timezone. The question is: how to determine the UTC time in a Google spreadsheet?